# Comment appelle-t-on les diplômés d'écoles de commerce et de management ?

Tags: vocabulaire

On appelle les diplômés d'écoles d'ingénieurs, les ingénieurs. Je me pose depuis quelques temps la question, sans trouver la réponse sur internet, de comment s'appellent les diplômés d'écoles de commerces et de management ? On peut en faire une blague et dire que ce sont des commerçants ! Ce n'est évidemment pas la vraie réponse !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de mot en français qui veut dire spécifiquement « diplômé d'une école de commerce ». Il n'y a pas non plus de mot qui veut dire spécifiquement « diplômé d'une école d'ingénieur ».

Le mot *ingénieur* désigne une profession : on est *ingénieur* si l'on exerce un métier d'ingénieur, ou que l'on veut l'exercer (ingénieur au chômage) ou qu'on l'a exercé (ingénieur à la retraite). Dans [certains pays](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ing%C3%A9nieur#Acc%C3%A8s_au_titre_et_%C3%A0_la_profession) (dont le Canada, mais pas la France), la profession d'ingénieur est réglementée : pour se dire *ingénieur*, il faut avoir une autorisation spécifique. Il faut en général avoir le diplôme pour obtenir cette autorisation, mais ce n'est pas automatique (par exemple, [au Québec](https://www.oiq.qc.ca/fr/jeSuis/candidat/obtenirUnPermis/cheminement/Pages/description.aspx), c'est de droit mais cela nécessite une démarche supplémentaire) et n'est pas forcément nécessaire. L'expression « diplômé d'une école d'ingénieur » est la manière idiomatique d'exprimer « diplômé d'une école d'ingénieur ».

De même, pour une école de commerce, lorsque l'on a le diplôme, on est « diplômé d'une école de commerce ». Si l'on exerce un métier consistant à vendre des choses, quel que soit le diplôme que l'on ait ou non, on est un ***[commercial](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commercial)***, un ***[vendeur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vendeur)*** ou un ***[marchand](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marchand)***. En général, la distinction entre un *vendeur* et un *commercial* est que le métier d'un commercial inclut à la fois de chercher les clients et de conclure des ventes, alors qu'un vendeur sert des clients qui ont pris l'initiative de le contacter. Quelqu'un qui travaille dans un magasin est un vendeur. Quelqu'un qui vend à des entreprises est un commercial. Quant à un *marchand*, il possède un magasin. Attention, cette distinction n'est pas toujours faite, et ces mots peuvent être interchangeables dans certains contextes. Une école de commerce prépare en général à un métier de commercial. Mais c'est le métier qui fait que l'on est un *commercial*, pas le diplôme.